# Is there a way to repeat a macro for different chunks in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

My data looks like this:

```
negative         Comment1    
neutral          Comment1    
positive         Comment1    
neutral          Comment1    
positive         Comment1    
negative         Comment1
```

I have a simple macro that I have written to do three steps:

1. Finds the most frequently used word in the first column
2. Deletes all other rows that do not contain this word
3. Deletes all duplicate rows.

Basically, my macro looks at what was written in the first column and reduces the entire chunk to only one row based on what word was the most frequently used.

An example:

[image]

This works so far, but now I would like to apply this same macro to different 'chunks' in an entire sheet. In reality, my data looks more like this:

```
positive         Comment1    
neutral          Comment1    
positive         Comment1    
negative         Comment1    
positive         Comment2    
neutral          Comment2    
positive         Comment2    
negative         Comment3    
negative         Comment3    
negative         Comment3    
positive         Comment3
```

And I want to essentially use my macro to reduce it to this:

```
positive         Comment1    
positive         Comment2    
negative         Comment3
```

So far, my macro only works for one comment. Is there a way I can detect differences in comments, for instance, so I can make my macro loop through each 'chunk' of similar comments? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here is my macro so far:

```
Sub MostFrequent()
Dim rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
xMax = 0
xOutValue = ""
For Each rng In WorkRng
    xValue = rng.Value
    If xValue <> "" Then
        dic(xValue) = dic(xValue) + 1
        xCount = dic(xValue)
        If xCount > xMax Then
            xMax = xCount
            xOutValue = xValue
        End If
    End If
Next

Dim xRow As Range
Dim xStr As String
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
xStr = xOutValue
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set xRow = WorkRng.Rows(i)
    Set rng = xRow.Find(xStr, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
       xRow.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = Range("A1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
        rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are really only using Column A and B.

The code below will insert formulas on Column C, D, and E.
(I could really only use 1 formula, left all 3 to be easier to understand what i'm doing)

With these formulas i get the times and % a comments gets repeated with a "Semantic".
If the percentage is lower than 50% it means that it is not the most frequent so it gets deleted. You are left with duplicates of the most frequent, I remove duplicates and the formulas.

```
Sub delRows()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, wk As Workbook, repeatDel As Boolean
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wk.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(2, 3).Formula = "=CONCAT(MID(B2,1,240),A2)"
        .Cells(2, 4).Formula = "=COUNTIF(C:C,C2)"
        .Cells(2, 5).Formula = "=D2/COUNTIF(B:B,B2)"
        'FillDown formulas
        .Range("C2:E" & lastRow).FillDown
        'When deleting rows, you should loop from bottom to top.
        For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 5) < 0.5 Then
                'Delete least frequent
                .Cells(i, 5).EntireRow.Delete
                repeatDel = True
            End If
        Next i
        'Remove duplicates and Formulas
        .Columns("A:E").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Header:=xlYes
        .Columns("C:E").ClearContents
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am having a mismatch issue when the comments are long: https://imgur.com/fgajI1J  Here is an example comment: _'Looking started he up perhaps against. How remainder all additions get elsewhere resources. One missed shy wishes supply design answer formed. Prevent on present hastily passage an subject in be. Be happiness arranging so newspaper defective affection ye.'_ What can I do about this? A lot of my comments are rather long.

Comment: Countif seems to error out after a comment of 247 characters. I have replaced the first formula with `=CONCAT(MID(B2,1,240),A2)`.

Comment: If you believe there may be comments were the first 240 characters are the same but different after, this may not be accurate then.